# APScheduler needs to be redefined on startup

Tags: python-3.x, file, sqlalchemy, jupyter-notebook, apscheduler

I'm using apscheduler on jupyter notebook to schedule cron jobs and I'm using the sqlalchemy jobstore.

Every time I open up the application I have to redefine the variables and as there is no physical job store file, the jobs are reset.

So my question is: How can I get that jobs.sqlite as a physical file?
And what is the proper technique for defining an apscheduler scheduler so that it doesn't have to be redefined every time?

```
import sqlalchemy
import pymongo
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from apscheduler.jobstores.mongodb import MongoDBJobStore
from apscheduler.jobstores.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemyJobStore
from apscheduler.executors.pool import ThreadPoolExecutor,     ProcessPoolExecutor
from apscheduler.triggers.cron import CronTrigger
import logging

logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger('apscheduler').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

jobstores = {
    'default': SQLAlchemyJobStore(url='sqlite:///jobs.sqlite'),
    'mongo': MongoDBJobStore()
}

executors = {
    'default': ThreadPoolExecutor(20),
    'processpool': ProcessPoolExecutor(5)
}

job_defaults = {
    'coalesce': False, 
    'max_instances': 100
}

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(jobstores=jobstores, executors=executors, job_defaults=job_defaults, timezone="Asia/Karachi")
scheduler.configure({'apscheduler.daemon': False})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

Instead of doing jobstores=jobstores in the last line.
You add another line:

```
scheduler.add_jobstore('sqlalchemy', url='sqlite:///jobs.sqlite')
```